# Change elements at given positions in an arma::vec with corresponding elements in other vector

Tags: c++, r, vector, rcpp, armadillo

I was wondering what is the most compact syntax in `Rcpp` to change given (noncontiguous) elements at positions `pos` in a vector `v1` with the corresponding elements in another vector (if I was using `arma::vec` class)? Say what in R I would do with

```
v1 = 1:10
pos = c(2,4,10)
v2 = c(3,8,2)
v1[pos] = v2
```

Is this possible without doing an explicit `for` loop?

Apologies if this is a trivial question...

Comment: Maybe look at [RcppArmadillo subsetting](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-subsetting/) for a start.

Comment: I had looked at that, but that was about subsetting, whereas in my case I wasn't sure about assigning selected elements new values... Guess it's trivial, but I am new to Rcpp & RcppArmadillo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer this question even though it really is already answered in the [Rcpp Gallery: RcppArmadillo Subsetting](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-subsetting/) post.

## Subsetting operations

In armadillo, the API has [submatrix views](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat) that enable this operation to take place.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec so_subset_params(arma::vec x, arma::uvec pos, arma::vec vals) {
    // Subset and set equal to
    x.elem(pos) = vals;
    return x;
}

/*** R
v1 = 1:10
pos = c(2,4,10)
v2 = c(3,8,2)
so_subset_params(v1, pos-1, v2)    
*/
```

This would give:

```
      [,1]
 [1,]    1
 [2,]    3
 [3,]    3
 [4,]    8
 [5,]    5
 [6,]    6
 [7,]    7
 [8,]    8
 [9,]    9
[10,]    2
```

## Replicating R Code in armadillo

To replicate your example 100% in armadillo, use:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void so_subset() {

  // --------------- 1:10
  arma::vec v1 = arma::linspace(1,10,10);

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Initial values of V1:" << std::endl << v1 << std::endl;

  // --------------- pos=c(2,4,10)

  // One style to create a subset index
  arma::uvec pos(3);
  pos(0) = 2; pos(1) = 4; pos(2) = 10;

  Rcpp::Rcout << "R indices pos:" << std::endl << pos << std::endl;


  // Adjust for index shift R: [1] => Cpp: [0]
  pos = pos - 1;

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Cpp indices pos:" << std::endl << pos << std::endl;


  // --------------- v2 = c(3,8,2)

  // C++98
  arma::vec v2;
  v2 << 3 << 8 << 2 << arma::endr;

  // C++11
  // arma::vec v2 = { 3, 8, 2}; // requires C++11 plugin

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Replacement values v2:" << std::endl << v2 << std::endl;

  // --------------- v1[pos] = v2

  // Subset and set equal to
  v1.elem(pos) = v2;

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Updated values of v1:" << std::endl << v1 << std::endl;
}

/*** R
so_subset()
*/
```

Thus, you would have the following output as it relates to each operation.

```
Initial values of V1:
    1.0000
    2.0000
    3.0000
    4.0000
    5.0000
    6.0000
    7.0000
    8.0000
    9.0000
   10.0000

R indices pos:
         2
         4
        10

Cpp indices pos:
        1
        3
        9

Replacement values v2:
   3.0000
   8.0000
   2.0000

Updated values of v1:
   1.0000
   3.0000
   3.0000
   8.0000
   5.0000
   6.0000
   7.0000
   8.0000
   9.0000
   2.0000
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation! That's fantastic! And apologies once again for the probably trivial question - I only started learning about Rcpp this week!